# R tmap print Italy

Tags: r, tmap

I want to draw a map. The country that I need to pront is Italy and I use this code:

```r
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(dplyr)
library(spData)
library(spDataLarge)
library(tmap) # for static and interactive maps
library(leaflet) # for interactive maps
library(ggplot2) # tidyverse data visualization package

map = tm_shape(it) + tm_fill() + tm_borders()

print(map)
```

If I write nz or world works but other contry not, why? How can I print Italy?
Exist another code? I don't find anything that works.

Comment: `nz` is a built-in dataset, meaning it's present already in `spData`. `it` is not. try ?nz.

Comment: how can i add Italy?

Comment: Either download the data yourself, or find a package that has the data as builtin

Comment: Where? I don't find anything. I need Italy with region but I don't know where I can download it

Comment: Here's a bank of shapefile for different countries: https://gadm.org/download_country.html.

Comment: How can I use it?

Comment: it's a shapefile. there are lots of documentations on how to open those in r, see e.g. [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19064/opening-shapefile-in-r)

Comment: Thanks! If I want add region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download, read, and plot a regional map of Italy in tmap like this:

```r
library(tmap)
library(sf)

url <- "https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/gadm/gadm4.0/shp/gadm40_ITA_shp.zip"

download.file(url, "../italia.zip")
unzip("../italia.zip", exdir = "italia")
It <- st_read("../italia/gadm40_ITA_2.shp")
map <- tm_shape(It) + tm_fill("NAME_1") + tm_borders()

print(map)
```

[image]

Comment: I have use this code but I can't see the region, I don't know how it is possible. Do you know?

Comment: Now this is my error Error: Fill argument neither colors nor valid variable name(s)

Comment: Can you restart your session then copy and paste my _exact_ code and run it again please? My example should be fully reproducible.